# Calling a JavaScript function within a loop

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cffunction

I have some geofence script that I am using on a cfm page:

```
<cfscript> 
 function getDistance(loclat, loclon, fencelat, fencelon, units = 'kilometers')
 { 
    // earth's radius. Default is miles.
    var radius = 3959;
    if (arguments.units EQ 'kilometers' )
        radius = 6371;
    else if (arguments.units EQ 'meters')
        radius = 6371393;
    else if (arguments.units EQ 'feet')
        radius = 20903520;

    var toRad = pi() / 180;
    var dLat = (fencelat-loclat) * toRad;
    var dLon = (fencelon-loclon) * toRad; 
    var a = sin(dLat/2)^2 + cos(loclat * toRad) * cos(fencelat * toRad) * sin(dLon/2)^2; 
    var c = 2 * createObject("java","java.lang.Math").atan2(sqr(a), sqr(1-a));

    return radius * c;

 }
</cfscript>
```

I then query my geofence table and the output lists for those records where geofences have been set for a particular device. When the geofence query returns multiple records, the `cfoutput` loops those records and as the code within the `cfoutput` calls the js function I get an error advising that the function has been called 2 times in the one template.

I "assume" the solution is to place the script function itself inside the `cfoutput` and make the function name unique by appending the recordid for each to the function name. Is this the correct solution?

If it is, my question is how can I dynamically append the record id to the function name within the cfscript? For example:

```
function getDistance#recid#(loclat, loclon, fencelat, fencelon, units = 'kilometers')
```

Then when I call for the function value, output

```
<cfif #fence_meter_radius# gt #getDistance(loclat, loclon, latitude, longitude, 'kilometers')#>
```

I welcome any assistance with the above.

Comment: are all those elements written in the javascript transferable as cf code ???, I would not consider myself as an advanced cf coder

Comment: By enclosing the function in `cfscript` tags it already *is* being treated as CF code. Whether or not it is valid CF code is a different question. Is your function supposed to be javascript or CF?

Comment: How did this one work out?